# Convert miliseconds to date and time and format by locale

Tags: java, android, date, time, milliseconds

How can I convert milliseconds to a time and date string and format it correctly like the user expects it to be?

I did the following:

```
((SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,Locale.getDefault())).format(new Date(Long.parseLong(timeInMilliseconds)));
```

Which seems to work, but I only get the date with this method.

Edit:

To clearify, I need to get the time/date pattern from system somehow to give each user his common format

Now I combined your solutions with mine and it seems to work like I expect.

```
private String getFormattedDateTimeString(Context context, String timeInMilliseconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateInstance = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat timeInstance = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timeInMilliseconds));
    String date = dateInstance.format(calendar.getTime());
    String time = timeInstance.format(calendar.getTime());
    return date + " " + time;
}
```

Why the hell do I get downvotes for this question???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the other answers are missing the point that the string representation of the date-time needs to be localized.

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library makes this work much easier.

Joda-Time leverages a [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine proper formatting of a date-time's string representation. The [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) class offers an option for "style" pattern as a way of generating a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). You specify a two character style pattern. The first character is the date style, and the second character is the time style. Specify a character of 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full. A date or time may be omitted by specifying a style character '-'.

If you do not specify a Locale or time zone, the JVM's default will be used.

## Locale

To create a [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), you need:

- Language code (either, see [combined list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes))

  - ISO 639 [alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1)
  - ISO 639 [alpha-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2)
- Country Code (either)

  - [ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)
  - [UN M.49 numeric-3 area code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M.49)

## Example Code

```
// Simulate input.
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.now().getMillis();

// Proceed with a 'long' value in hand.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( millisecondsSinceEpoch, DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Riyadh" );
DateTime dateTimeRiyadh = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZone );

// 'ar' = Arabic, 'SA' = Saudi Arabia.
java.util.Locale locale = new Locale( "ar", "SA" ); // ( language code, country code );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( locale ).withZone( timeZone );
String output = formatter.print( dateTimeUtc );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "millisecondsSinceEpoch: " + millisecondsSinceEpoch );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeRiyadh: " + dateTimeRiyadh );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
millisecondsSinceEpoch: 1392583624765
dateTimeUtc: 2014-02-16T20:47:04.765Z
dateTimeRiyadh: 2014-02-16T23:47:04.765+03:00
output: 16 فبراير, 2014 AST 11:47:04 م
```

Comment: Thank you, looks promising. I´ll try that when I´m at home

Answer (score 1):

Leaving your code as is, just change:
Instead of

```
getDateInstance
```

try

```
getDateTimeInstance
```

Or, you'd better use:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String datetime = fmt.format(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS";

// Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

// Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);

String formatedDate =  formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");// you can rearange it as you like

 cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMilliseconds); //convert the time in milli to a date

 String date = format.format(cal.getTime());// here you get your time formated
```

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth do you want to use a calendar object???? It's just a waste of resources.

```
// Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

String formatedDate =  myDateFormat.format(new Date(timeInMilliseconds));
```